# How to make angular bindings work on dynamically created dom items?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to make constructor of web page. Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N2knCv17rQqPBK5Pl5rG?p=preview). I have headings, paragraphs, lists and so on. I drag them from menu and they are cloned and pasted into dom.
Similar to this one [layoutit.com](http://www.layoutit.com/build_v3/startWithLayout/layout/2).
This is how they are cloned:

```
app.directive('ironplayDraggableBox', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $(element).draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".column",
        helper: function(){
          $new_el = $(this).clone().draggable({disabled: true});
          return $compile($new_el)(scope);
        },

        handle: ".drag",
        drag: function(e, t) {
            t.helper.width(400)
        },
        stop: function(e, t) {
          t.helper.attr('style', '');
        }
     });

    }
  };
}]);
```

I want each element that is created to have some buttons for options: text align, color, etc. This buttons change class of the element that resides in the `.view` div. I do it via directive and jQuery. Here the html code of element:

```
<div class="box" ironplay-draggable-box>
        <a href="#close" class="remove label label-danger">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> remove
        </a>
        <span class="drag label label-default">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i> drag
        </span>

        <span class="configuration">
            <select name="align" ironplay-text-align>
                <option value="">Align</option>
                <option value="text-left">Left</option>
                <option value="text-right">Right</option>
                <option value="text-center">Center</option>
            </select>

            <select name="emphasis" ironplay-emphasis>
                <option value="">Emphasis</option>
                <option value="text-muted">Muted</option>
                <option value="text-primary">Primary</option>
                <option value="text-success">Success</option>
                <option value="text-info">Info</option>
                <option value="text-warning">Warning</option>
                <option value="text-danger">Danger</option>
            </select>
        </span>

        <div class="xpreview">Title</div>
        <div class="view">
            <h3 contenteditable="true">h3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I make it via binding like so:

```
 <select name="align" ng-model="text-align">
```

and updated automatically as class name:

```
<h3 contenteditable="true" class="{{text-align}}">h3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
```

Comment: Direct me to a fiddle or plunker of the minimum working code and I can edit the code to produce the result

Comment: ok, thnx. just a minute

Comment: @Mwayi Here the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/N2knCv17rQqPBK5Pl5rG?p=info Align still not works (weird !?), but idea is clear

Comment: I'll do this a bit later but the workflow should be something like 1) draggabble-directive should simply contain a config object, 2) on drop the droppable-directive should use the config to create a 'stencil' with a new scope. 3) this stencil-directive which has an ng-template loaded in (based on configs in [2]) should create a new scope where you will manage changes of ng-models via the standard controller-view bindings i.e. scope.$watch('align')